# Navbar wraps down to second line despite having enough space on the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.0 and my navbar wraps down to second line despite having enough space on the right to fit another item. If I reduce the font size, it just shrinks in size but still remains wrapped. How do I keep it in one line?

Image : http://i59.tinypic.com/16knkvo.png

Here is the code:

```css
.navbar{
  height: 25%;
  background-color: #FCE218;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.navbar-header,.nav,.navbar-nav,.navbar-brand{
  height: 100%;

}

.nav-margin{
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.nav-link-font{
  color: #FF4325;
}

.nav-link-active-font{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #18740B;
}

.nav-link-font,.nav-link-active-font{
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #0B2D13;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-item{
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="container-fluid navbar" role="navigation">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="images/HeaderImg.png" alt="Aamantran - Alphonso Mangoes" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-margin">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active nav-item"><a class="nav-link-active-font" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link-font" href="#">Why Aamantran?</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link-font" href="#">Quality Assurance</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link-font" href="#">Recipes</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link-font" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone here had posted an answer asking me to set navbar-nav width to 100%. Well, somewhere around 60% worked for me! He deleted that answer posted for some reason I cant guess. But thank you all for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `margin-right` you are applying to the `nav-item` class. You are using a percentage rather than an absolute value. Change it to this and it will stop wrapping:

```
.nav-item{
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.I am new to CSS and I had read somewhere that in responsive web designing, it is a good practice to use percentages instead of pixels. So I'm trying to use that guideline as far as possible. I appreciate your help though.